# Does having an extended validation SSL certificate increase your Google search ranking?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, security-certificate

I am assisting an retailer obtain and install an extended validation (EV) SSL certificate for their online shop. After a week of back and forth paperwork with the CA, I wonder whether it's worth the time and expense of getting one.

CAs, of course, claim it makes your site more trustworthy. There are numerous articles, however, arguing users can't tell the difference and don't care. Moreover, most modern browsers no longer make a visual distinction between EV and standard certificates.

Clearly, EV certificates lost the clout it once had, but I wonder if Google's ranking algorithm still gives it a higher weight. I suspect it's at least a small factor for smaller online retailers, but less, or none at all, for those that have been "prevalidated" by the virtue of buying Google Ads.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard any mention from Google that EV certs affect ranking compared to DV certs, and the only material I can find about it online is [people who also say that Google has never mentioned this, and people who are speculatively guessing one way or the other](https://www.quora.com/Is-EV-SSL-better-for-SEO-than-a-regular-SSL).

So here's my own speculative guess: I would be incredibly surprised, if [after Google stopped treating EV and DV certificates differently in the Chrome address bar](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/08/12/google_chrome_extended_validation_certificates/), that they still treat them differently in their ranking algorithm. That is, if they ever ranked EV and DV sites differently in the first place.

Comment: I would be surprised too, the world (except CAs) seems to go slowly out of the EV thing that is basically a failure (look at all major websites: very few use EV certificates).

Comment: @Maxmillian Laumeister,  my question was closed because it was deemed to be a duplicate of a question you had answered over 3 years ago.  I requested it should be reopened because the other question was answered over 3 years ago. A great deal of changes has happened since that time. Can you help request it?

Comment: @ATL_DEV I didn't answer that question 3 years ago, I just edited it for grammar yesterday so my icon shows up on it. On Stack Exchange, threads are evergreen, so it's just as easy for someone to post an updated answer on the 3 year old post. The dupe closing process just makes sure that future answers all accrue in the same place so they're easier for people to find and compare. If you want an old post to get more attention, you can always bump it by [adding a bounty](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Yeah, but the fact that I couldn't find it the first time says the titling could be a bit better. Instead of closing questions with answer, perhaps SE should merge the questions and answers with alternative titles.

Comment: @ATL_DEV Duplicate questions remain on the site permanently unlike other types of closures, so this closed question will remain forever searchable! If at some point you do find a question that has a poor title and/or grammar mistakes, please consider submitting an edit. Stephen greatly improved the title of the other question through his own edit yesterday. I do agree that SE should have a merge function, but dupe closures are really not too bad since they link the questions and they don't delete anything.

Comment: @ATL_DEV " A great deal of changes has happened since that time." Not a lot. It can be summarized by: browsers continue to hide more and more from the URL, "green bar" becomes out of fashion and hence EV has no more specific value on browsers see https://www.troyhunt.com/extended-validation-certificates-are-dead/, HTTP is dumped in favor of HTTPS, and newer CAs like Let's Encrypt generate short term (3 months) certificates.